# (PHP + MySQL) How to show field disabled by gray collor While using readonly and still can submit data

Tags: php, mysql, readonly

Define Colors With RGBA Values

Add the Following code under style

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#p7 {background-color:rgba(215,215,215,1);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

id="p7">Disabled Grey none transparent

Simple Example as follow

```
    <!-- this appear in request shown disabled by gray color -->
    <input id="p7" type="textbox" name="prn" value="100" readonly="readonly"" /> 

</form>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO41z.png)

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve, because there may be better options

Comment: All I'm trying to do is help people how are looking for an answer like this, as I did look all over the internet to achieve the above result

Comment: Have you got a question? This is a question and answer site. If you just want to show off your working code then make a blog or upload it to GitHub or something

Answer (score 0):

I did use the following code but it is not working so I had make my work around as above

```
 <input readonly style="color: Grey; opacity: 1; ">
```

An other solution tested and works

```
<tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#p8').submit(function () {
    $("input").prop('disabled', false);

    //Rest of code
    })
});
</script>
<td align="right">Employee Name</td>
<td><input id="p8" type="text" name="name" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['name'].'"'); ?>Disabled /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```